# How to retrieve xml file sub-element value in php?

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file `36031P_new.xml` in which I am trying to retrieve xml sub-element value in php.

The snippets of the content present in the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StringAssetInfo>
    <attrName>CASE_SERIES_TITLE_FRENCH</attrName>
    <attrTagName>CASE_SERIES_TITLE_FRENCH</attrTagName>
    <value>PrimeTime Politics avec Dusen</value>
</StringAssetInfo>
<StringAssetInfo>
    <attrName>CASE_SERIES_TITLE</attrName>
    <attrTagName>CASE_SERIES_TITLE</attrTagName>
    <value>PrimeTime Politics</value>
</StringAssetInfo>
```

I have tried with the following **php code** but I am getting error **Error: Cannot create object.**

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("36031P_new.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
?>
<td style="width:8%;">
    <?php echo $xml->StringAssetInfo[1]->attrName . "<br>"; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: What is returning the error? The load file? Because that XML is not well-formed as it is lacking a root element.

Comment: I am getting the error **Error: Cannot create object.**

Comment: Oh that message is in the `die()`. Well, like I said, that's not well-formed XML. Get well-formed XML is the first option. Is that the full content of the XML?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes, you are right. Its not well-formed because I am trying to test something with very less content in the xml. The actual content is quite big.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I have pasted my xml [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cf06j4ex/1/) (sorry, its quite big). I am trying to pull info. from line# 190 to 194

Comment: @ChrisWhite I am wondering what is the best way to pull information from line#190 to 194.

Comment: See my edit for how to do what you want

Comment: That's a horrible abuse of jsfiddle.net. Next time try pastebin.com or something meant to handle large amounts of text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get what you seem to want is XPath:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test2.xml') or die('Unable to load XML');

// Find the attrName with the desired text, then go up a level to get the parent node.
$path = $xml->xpath('//StringAssetInfo/attrName[text()="CPAC_SERIES_TITLE"]/..');

var_dump($path);
```

OUTPUT:

```
iridium:~ cwhite$ php -f bigxml.php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (3) {
    ["attrName"]=>
    string(17) "CPAC_SERIES_TITLE"
    ["attrTagName"]=>
    string(17) "CPAC_SERIES_TITLE"
    ["value"]=>
    string(18) "PrimeTime Politics"
  }
}
```

Comment: They didn't indicate anywhere that they wanted to filter by a certain text.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Thanks Chris, it looks great. The var_dump($path) gives 3 fields and values. I am wondering if there is any way if we can extract only `"PrimeTime Politics"`

Comment: The return in `$path` is obviously an array as we see in the `var_dump`, so it's as simple as `echo $path[0]->value`.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56117670/look-for-a-mp4-file-inside-a-directory-and-send-it-to-different-directory-after). Although, its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.