# look for a mp4 file inside a directory and send it to different directory after converting to mp3 in php?

Tags: php, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a directory called **incoming_folder** in which there is a **mp4 file.**

What I want to achieve through php code is to scan a **incoming_folder** directory, look for an mp4 file and send it to **outgoing_folder** after converting it into mp3.

Technically **outgoing_folder** should have *mp3 version of mp4* from **incoming_folder**

Here is the pictorial representation of what I want:

[image]

Tried with the following code although its scanning the incoming_folder directory but no conversion is happening through ffmpeg.

```
<?php
$dir    = 'in_folder';  /* Place where mp4 file is present */
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);    /* It lists all the files in a directory including mp4 file*/

$destination = 'out_folder';  /* Place where mp3 file need to be send after conversion from mp4 */

    <?php
    foreach($files1 as $f)
    {
      $parts = pathinfo($f);

      switch($parts['extension'])
      {
        case 'mp4' :
          system('ffmpeg -i '.$f.' -map 0:2 -ac 1 '.$destination.DS. $parts['filename'].'.mp3', $result);

          if ($result) {
            // Do something with result if you want
            // log for example
          }
          break;

        case 'mp3' :
          // copy($f, $destination. DS . $parts['filename']. '.' . $parts['extension']);
          copy($f, $destination.DS.$parts['filename'].'.mp3');
          break;  
      }
    }
    ?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code so that conversion of file happens from **incoming_folder** and it should go to **outgoing_folder**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see is that you are passing the file name only to ffmpeg, not the file path. You need to prepend `$dir.DS` to the file name.

```
<?php
$filePath = $dir . DS . $f;
system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);
```

After I fixed that, ffmpeg failed, complaining about your stream map parameters. I changed them to this and it worked, YMMV.

```
<?php           
system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 ' . $destination . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);
```

Edit: Full updated code

```
<?php
const DS = '/';
$dir    = 'in_folder';  /* Place where mp4 file is present */
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);    /* It lists all the files in a directory including mp4 file*/

$destination = 'out_folder';  /* Place where mp3 file need to be send after conversion from mp4 */


foreach ($files1 as $f)
{

    $parts = pathinfo($f);
    switch ($parts['extension'])
    {
        case 'mp4' :
            $filePath = $dir . DS . $f;
            system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 ' . $destination . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);

            if ($result)
            {
                // Do something with result if you want
                // log for example
            }
            break;

        case 'mp3' :
            // copy($f, $destination. DS . $parts['filename']. '.' . $parts['extension']);
            copy($f, $destination . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats the only place I need to make changes ?

Comment: Yeah, just pass in the file path instead of just the bare file name. And then make sure your ffmpeg flags are correct.

Comment: These are the changes I did;

    `case 'mp4' :
   $filePath = $dir. DS .$f;
   echo $filePath;
      system('ffmpeg -i '.$filePath.' -map 0:2 -ac 1 '.$destination.DS. $parts['filename'].'.mp3', $result);`

Comment: Yeah, that will allow ffmpeg to find the input file.

Comment: I did echo $filePath; it shows the following o/p on the webpage `incoming_folderDS36031P.mp4`

Comment: why did you use this `' -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 '` ?

Comment: I'm assuming DS is a constant you have for directory separators, I added that to my example, just posted. If you don't already have that defined, you need to define it or use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193289/discussion-between-rob-ruchte-and-flash).